# clearing css floats is not working as expected

Tags: css, css-float

I've read several articles about this like http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ or http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-clearing-of-floats/ and all suggest the same tricks but they do not work for me.
HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="head">
                <div id="columns">              
                    <div id="result_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper">
                        <div id="result_length" class="dataTables_length">
                        <div class="dataTables_scroll">
                            <div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0pt none; width: 100%;">
                                <div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="width: 1017px;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow: auto; height: 570px; width: 100%;">
                                <table id="result" style="margin-left: 0pt; width: 100%;">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="result_info" class="dataTables_info">Showing 1 to 2 of 451 entries</div>
                    <div id="result_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="foot">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My footer div has a margin-top which is ignored or the margin is calculated from the wrong element. The footer appears within the container div instead below it. Issue is identical in IE8 and FF 9.0.1

Any ideas?

EDIT:

CSS:

```
div#head {
    position: absolute;
    width:1000px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}
div#foot {    
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

div#columns {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    top: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}

div#wrapper {

    position:relative;

    margin-left:auto;

    margin-right:auto;

    top: 20px;

    width:1000px;

}
```

Note: I'm using datatables plugin. part of the html is generated by that plugin (including the inline styles.
The css for that is too long to fully post here.

Some datatables css:

```
.dataTables_info {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}

.dataTables_paginate {
    width: 44px;
    * width: 50px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

EDIT 2:

Screenshot of the issue after applying Scotts fix (which does not help either)

[image: div id="columns"]

[image: div id="foot"]

[image: Firebug HTML Panel]

Note that the markup in columns is created in JQuerys $(document).ready function. Maybe that causes the issue?

EDIT 3:

I tried jsFiddle however while the clear float fixes work there they disrupt the display of the datatable.

clear float trick from scott applied: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yApAh/6/

footer is right but the rest of the table is wrong

without clear trick:
http://jsfiddle.net/yApAh/7/

here footer is wrong but datatable is displayed as desired.

Comment: .wrapper { margin: 0 auto } ?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle of your bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest posting your CSS code to acompany this, as for your footer set another divider above the footer that clears all floats

```
 <div style="clear:both; height: 1px;"></div>
```

Then the margin will work on the footer.

Comment: You need to post your CSS otherwise it will not work, without knowing where the floats are it is impossible to know where to put the footer and the div

Answer (score 0):

Which bits are floated? If it's the div's within #columns you need to use `overflow:hidden` not `overflow:auto`

Answer (score 0):

Always use the '[The Easy Clearing Method](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)' as it works in all cases and all browsers in all modes.

```
#columns:before, 
#columns:after { 
   content: ""; 
   display: table; 
}
#columns:after { 
   clear: both; 
}
#columns { 
   *zoom: 1; 
}
```

If you like you can check out my [css framework](http://simpl.romack.net/) .

Comment: also does not help. See screenshots. Markup in columns is created in JQuery $(document).ready